# Redimensionar Vídeos en HTML y CSS

Tags: html, css, html5, html-video

quiero poner un vídeo en mi página web realizada con HTML y CSS, el vídeo me gustaria que estuviera en la parte de arriba, y que me abarque el 100% de ancho, pero de alto que pudiera estar a un 50%, sin embargo no logro redimensionar la altura del vídeo, me gustaría saber si hay alguna forma y si me pudieran ayudar, de antemano, muchas gracias. :)

Me gustaría que se viera algo así, como en esta página: https://www.pexels.com/es-es/videos/

Siento que su altura es de aproximadamente un 50%-80%

Código HTML:

```
<div class="h">
        <div class="tit_index_video">
            <h1>Pasión por el empoderamiento y el reconocimiento</h1>
        </div>
        <video onloadstart="this.muted=true" autoplay loop>
                    <source src="videos/video1.mp4">
        </video>
</div>
```

Código CSS:

```
.h {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50%;
    position: relative;
}

video {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50%;
}
```

Comment: Puedes colocar el vídeo al 100% de ancho, pero el alto sería siempre el que corresponda con el *aspect-ratio* del mismo. Si quieres *forzar* a un alto específico se pierde esa relación de aspecto, por lo que tu video se verá *extraño*. Toma eso en cuenta. Saludos

Comment: Podrías controlar el video como background de un contenedor padre, y a ese padre puedes establecerle una altura cualquiera, de esta forma posicionas el video de forma absoluta relativa al padre. Para evitar que se "desencuadre" el video, aplicas en su CSS `object-fit: cover;`

Answer (score 0):

```css
<style>
.hero {
    position: relative;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    justify-content: center;
    padding: 1.15rem;
    padding-top: 74px;
    padding-bottom: 66px;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #d3d3d3;
    text-decoration: none;
    height: 100%;
    max-height: 500px;
    min-height: 380px;
    z-index: 1;
}
</style>
```

```html
<div class="hero">
<center><h1>Pasión por el empoderamiento y el reconocimiento</h1></center>
<video autoplay="" loop="" muted="">
<!-- cambias esa url por tu video y tipo de video. (en tu caso sera: video/mp4) -->
<source src="https://static.pexels.com/lib/videos/free-videos.webm" type="video/webm">
</video>
</div>
```

Creo que eso pude servirte para guiarte:(

Comment: Ayudaría le expliques que modificaste

Answer (score 0):

Solamente agrega un `max-height` al contenedor `.h` y `overflow: hiden;`

```
.h {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    max-height: 50vh; /* si quieres que ocupe la mitad de la pantalla, sino coloca px. */
    overflow: hidden; /* escondes lo que queda de video despues del porcentaje especificado */
}
```

No es necesario redimencionar la altura del video. Lógicamente con esto ocultas una parte del video, por lo que no se mostrará el contenido completo del mismo.

Answer (score 0):

Hola buena aquí tu video se ve de fondo y al mitad de tu pantalla usando `height: 50vh;` en el `div.h` y luego agregas `overflow: hidden;`. Lo unico malo es que se ve recortado. Espero que te sirva.

```css
.h{
  width: 100%;
  height: 50vh;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.title{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  color: white;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

video { 
  width: 100%;
  heigth: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-size: cover;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="h">
        <div class="title">
            <h1>Pasión por el empoderamiento y el reconocimiento</h1>
        </div>
        <video autoplay= "autoplay" loop="" muted="">
          <source src="https://static.pexels.com/lib/videos/free-videos.webm"   type="video/webm">
        </video>
</div>
```